# virtualenv returns [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, python3, virtualenv

I am trying to start a new virtual environment in my folder.

I have Python3, Python2 and virtualenv installed, it doesn't seem to be a dependency problem.

I do the command:

```
sudo virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

**Note** that I have already tried chmod 777 and tried doing it with and without sudo.

This command returns me:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /foo/bar/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /foo/bar/venv/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /foo/bar/venv/bin/python3 could not be run: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I don't know if it has something to do, but I am using an SSD.

Comment: Is /foo mounted noexec?

Comment: @bbaassssiiee how can I know that?

Comment: grep foo /etc/fstab|grep noexec

Comment: @bbaassssiiee it didn't show anything and the problem keeps happening